# Django showing error while saving data into a model: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'id' cannot be null")

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.5

I am writing a script which can pull data from different API's and store into a MySQL database. This application will run from command line. So I am only using Django's ORM.

But when I am creating a model which doesn't have primary key but have a column named id. When I am trying to save data in this model I am getting a error ***django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'id' cannot be null")***

I am really confused why this happens. Because from API I get values from id column and there is no chance to get null or empty value for this column.

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Here is my model:

```
class Graphite(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'graphite'

    id = models.BigIntegerField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
```

And this is the code when I am trying to save data in this model:

```
    Graphite.objects.using('database_name').create(
      id=row['id'],
      full_name=row['full_name'],
      email=row['email'],
      status=row['status'])
```

When saving data into model I am using *Graphite.objects.using('database_name').* because I have multiple database connected in this application.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure did you use django migrations, but it won't let you create this kind of model in django, where your id property (in model) hasn't primary key as its parameter (mySQL). So why don't you just define:

```
class Graphite(models.Model):   

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'graphite'           

    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
```

so set primary_key on id? Then you wouldn't have to pass id when creating `Graphite`.

BUT

If you have to provide `id` which is something you need to have in every `Graphite` model and it's something different than primary key, then just define it different, let's say `row_id`. But you should still have at last one `id` property in your model with `primary_key` set to `True` when you want to have `id` as `BigIntegerField`.

**EDIT (on the example)**

In mySQL execute this command:

```
ALTER TABLE graphite ADD COLUMN row_id BIGINT;
```

Then your model should looks like this:

```
class Graphite(models.Model):   

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'graphite'           

    row_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
```

And usage:

```
Graphite.objects.using('database_name').create(
  row_id=row['id'],
  full_name=row['full_name'],
  email=row['email'],
  status=row['status'])
```

and that's it.

Comment: I didn't use django migration and also removed the migration table from database.

Comment: So couldn't you follow steps I provided in an answer? Isn't that you're looking for?

Comment: @SirajusSalayhin I've edited the answer. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have a primary key.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).

So, you have to make your `id` field a primary key by adding `primary_key=True`. Then, it won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `id` from default django table `id`.

so there is no `id` for primary key. Just make it `primary=True`. or use another `id` like `graphaite_id`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your primary key, make sure you have your `primary=True` and to store your `id` make another column for it